# Drop down selection track by Id Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have following data for drop down in my controller.

```
 $scope.groups={{"gpId": 3, "name" :"Tom"}, {"gpId": 32, "name" :"Helen"},{"gpId": 9, "name" :"Amy"}

 $scope.user=
 {
   tkId: 32;
   place: NW
  }
```

In my html I have following select

```
   <select ng-model="user.tkId" ng-options="a.gpId as a.name for a in groups track by a.gpId></select>
```

When I run this I get drop down with Helen selected but when i want to change the selection from drop down it doesn't let me. 
Please let me know how I can change it to select other options so I can save it if needed. Thanks

Comment: throw it in a js fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet works.

First, an array of objects is written like this `[{}, {}]`

[It's written in the angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-) that `track by` and `as` should not be used together.

> Don't use `select as` and `track by` in the same expression. They're not designed to work together.

```
<body ng-app="selectExample">
  <script>
    angular.module('selectExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.groups = [{
          "gpId": 3,
          "name": "Tom"
        }, {
          "gpId": 32,
          "name": "Helen"
        }, {
          "gpId": 9,
          "name": "Amy"
        }];
        $scope.user = {
          tkId: 32,
          place: 'NW'
        };
      }]);
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <label>Group:
      <select ng-model="user.tkId" ng-options="group.gpId as group.name for group in groups"></select>
    </label>
    <br/> {{user.tkId}}
  </div>
</body>
```